# checking when all data is sent using non-blocking open

Tags: python, c, linux, io, blocking

If I open a a file as `os.open( '/dev/ttyS2', O_RDWR | O_NDELAY )`, is there any way that I can check when my 'write()' commands have finished? Or, can I open a file for non-blocking read but blocking write?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding of what non-blocking means.  It does **not** imply asynchronous operation - you can have any combination of asynchronous/synchronous and blocking/non-blocking.

A `write()` just hands data off to the kernel to take care of.  When `write()` returns successfully, the kernel has now taken care of the data - this is true regardless of whether the file descriptor is blocking or non-blocking.  Whether or not the kernel has actually finished writing it at this point is a separate matter (usually, the answer is "no" - most file descriptors are asynchronous).

A `write()` cannot complete if the kernel has no more room to buffer the data you want to write, and this is the case that is affected by non-blocking versus blocking - in the blocking case, the `write()` will block until space is available.  In the non-blocking case, `write()` will return an error (`EAGAIN`), and it is up to you to retry it later.

If you wish to wait until all data written to a terminal device has actually been sent to the hardware, use `tcdrain()` - but this is likely to be unnecessary.  Alternatively, if you wish `write()` to block until your data is accepted by the kernel, then you can use `fcntl()` to temporarily set the file descriptor to blocking.

Comment: This is not quite correct. Even in nonblocking mode, a `write` to ordinary files and possibly certain devices will "block" pending the availability of buffer space. Nonblocking mode only works correctly for sockets and an implementation-specific collection of other file descriptor types (likely including terminal devices/serial ports).

Comment: @R.: A `write` to ordinary files that has to wait does not block - it "Disk Waits".

Answer (score 3):

If you are writing to a tty (as you are in your example), you can use `termios.tcdrain` to wait until all written bytes have been transmitted.

Your `write` systems calls will still be non-blocking, so you will need to handle `EWOULDBLOCK`/`EAGAIN` errors, and use `select(2)`, `poll(2)` or `epoll(7)` to know when you can write to the file descriptor. These are designed to be used with non-blocking file descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

The O_NDELAY flag always affects both reading and writing. To achieve a blocking write on a non-blocking file you can select (Python module) the file and write when it becomes writable in a loop.

Comment: Are you sure select.select() will block with a non-blocking file descriptor? Or did you mean a different select module method

Comment: @Falmarri: Yes, `select()` blocks with non-blocking file descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

OS API write() returns count of written bytes. Checking this value against size of your input you can see when all input is sent.

Answer (score 0):

Open two file descriptors to the same location - one for non-blocking reads and the other for blocking writes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `os.fsync(fd)`?

Comment: On further research, apparently not.  Looks like camh's tcdrain is the way to go.